# Without Skolem–Mahler–Lech Theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Using [Skolem–Mahler–Lech theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Mahler%E2%80%93Lech_theorem) one can easily prove the $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left|\Re\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2} \right)^n\right|  =+\infty$.

Is there a "simple way" to prove this without using this nice theorem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705877 , with a nice elementary proof by Noam Elkies.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of an answered on another Stack Exchange site; new answers should be placed there.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705877/an-exotic-sequence